# How can I pull ID from a form control in a datagrid / repeater (vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, repeater, linkbutton

I have the following repeater

```
<asp:Repeater id="weatherFeed" Runat="server"><ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="PickInfo" onClick="Selection_PickInfo">
     <img src="images/mapPin.png" title="<%#Container.DataItem("city")%>" />
    </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

I'd like to call my function "Selection_PickInfo" using the Link buttons created, but I'm having the issue of not being able to actually pull information from these links.

Comment: Can you show the code you have used to try to pull data with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In your function just do Sender.ID

Answer (score 0):

you have a link button in the repeater that's why you are not able to use the link button functionality.you have to find the link button in the weatherFeed_ItemDataBound event then attach your
Selection_PickInfo then it will work fine.Try this .....

```
LinkButton pickInfo = (LinkButton)weatherFeed.FindControl("PickInfo");
            pickInfo.Attributes["onclick"] = "Selection_PickInfo();";
```

Comment: i dont know Vb i just show you thae way how to get the id using C# u can write in Vb if know how to write in Vb ok good Luck

Comment: I feel like this is getting there. I'm attempting to work this into a working solution, i'm 100% sure FindControl is the answer though! My issue would be how do I assign the value of container.dataitem("city") to the linkbutton.

Comment: What would I be binding that too? (Text, ID, etc.) I'll accept once I've got it figured out, I don't want to confuse others that come here for same issue. I want to be able to post the correct solution

Comment: you have to bind Text with the data base Text='<%#Bind("City") %>'

Comment: The issue with doing this is it removes my previous text from the link button (i.e. the img). Just to note I tried making it the CssClass and this worked. The problem is with this I can't pull it: response.write(b.Parent.FindControl("pickInfo").CssClass) because I get the error 'CssClass' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'

Comment: obviously you cant use CssClass in the web page during Find Controle you doing wrong because there is no such kind of property to find a control with the Css Class you have to do it as i mention the code above to find the control then it will work fine other you keep stuck in error because web.ui.control and css are two very differnt thing ........